# How to use lower version of keras and tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, libraries

I'm running a code which requires keras version 1.2.0 and tensorflow version 1.1.0.
I'm using Jupyter notebook and I created an [environment](https://github.com/llSourcell/How_to_simulate_a_self_driving_car/blob/master/environments.yml) for all the dependencies.

However, I mistakenly installed both libraries again through pip command which installed the latest versions.

I closed the notebook, opened it again and created the environment once again so the older version of both libraries were installed again.

But when I run `keras.__version___` command, it shows 2.4.3, which i do not want.

I also ran `conda remove keras --force` and `pip uninstall keras`, but it's still showing the latest version.

The code is only compatible with the older version. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because it is getting uninstalled on a different environment. Identify which python and pip executable you are using by running the following commands:

```sh
$ which pip
$ which python
```

These two commands will give out the path of the executable from which we can determine the environment. If it is different from what you were using you can try installing to the desired environment by running:

```sh
/path/to/desired/pip uninstall keras
/path/to/desired/pip install keras==1.2.0
```